# phalconphp routing and add postfix to action

Tags: php, phalcon

I'd like to add to phalconphp routing rule. When method is POST then call to controller x, action x+Post postfix + params

```
$router->addPost('/:action/:params',['controller'=>'print','action'=>1."Post",'params'=>2]);
```

and

```
$router->addPost('/:action/:params',['controller'=>'print','action'=>str_replace(1,1.'Post',1),'params'=>2]);
```

but it not work. Any idea on solve?

Comment: I solved problem. Maybe will be helpful to someone.

In router:

`$router->add('/:action/:params',['controller'=>'controllerName','action'=>1,'params'=>2])->via(['POST'])->convert('action',function($action){
    return $action.'Post';
});`

Comment: you should put this in an answer and mark it as such. Answering your own question is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clear look:

In router:

```
$router->add('/:action/:params',
            ['controller'=>'controllerName',
             'action'=>1,
             'pa‌​rams'=>2])
       ->via(['POST'])
       ->convert('action',
                  function($action){ 
                      return $action.'Post'; 
                  });
```

More information @docs:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#http-method-restrictions

```
// This route will be matched if the HTTP method is POST or PUT
$router->add("/products/update")->via(array("POST", "PUT"));
```

Convertions allow to freely transform the route’s parameters before passing them to the dispatcher, the following examples show how to use them:

```
//The action name allows dashes, an action can be: /products/new-ipod-nano-4-generation
$router
    ->add('/products/{slug:[a-z\-]+}', array(
        'controller' => 'products',
        'action' => 'show'
    ))
    ->convert('slug', function($slug) {
        //Transform the slug removing the dashes
        return str_replace('-', '', $slug);
    });
```